# Use onTouch to ignore onClick

Tags: java, android

I event handlers for both `onTouch` and `onClick` set up. I would like the `onTouch` event to be able to block the `onClick`. How would I do this?

If `onTouch` conditions are met, then `onClick` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Android Framework if you implement the onTouchListener for that View

```
 @Override
   boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
         case R.id.send:
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //when the user has pressed the button
                    //do the needful here
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //when the user releases the button
                    //do the needful here
                    break;
            }`enter code here`
            break;
     }
     return true;
 }
```

onTouch Method return true will block the other action including the click event

Answer (score 0):

Just return true from the onTouch listener, and a click will never register.